# Joomla plugin search not working

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, search

I upgraded my Joomla site from 1.5 to 2.5 and a few weeks ago to 3.4. I realised that my search didn't work. It returned a white blank page.

I struggled over some articles on the web that a broken plugin could be the reason. So I disabled every search plugin and activated it step by step.

Finally my `plg_search_content` the reason. So I downloaded a fresh installation of Joomla 3 and extracted the `com_search` from the `components` and `administrator` folder. But with no luck.

Last but not least a white blank page is shown if I enable `plg_search_content`. Hopefully someone can help me to clearify this.

**TL;DR: Fresh overriding folders didn't help as of installed plugins, components and modules**

Comment: Could you please re-enable the search plugin, then go to your Global Configuration and set Error Reporting to **Development**. Once done, refresh the page and report back any errors that are shown

Comment: @Lodder that's the problem with that - I do have **Development** enabled as Error_Reporting. But just getting a blank page and my apache error.log is also empty

Comment: it's possible that your **php.ini** is overriding the the error reporting settings.

Comment: @Lodder unfortunately not... every other 500er or else is going straight to be logged by **error.log**.

Comment: Ok, from the fresh Joomla 3.4 you downloaded, could you try extracting the following folders: **libraries**, **administrator**, **components**, **libraries**, **plugins** and **modules**. Before doing this, please backup your current site

Comment: Still no luck - I have to say I do have some plugins, components and modules. So I can't copy a fresh folder.

Comment: Copying the folders I mentioned above won't delete any 3rd party extensions you have installed. It will simply override the Joomla core folders/file. There must be a way to see what the error is as a blank screen means there is one but error reporting isn't enabled to the max

Comment: @Lodder I copied the folders. I made a copy of that folders for backup and copied the fresh Joomla folders into it. So I've overidden those files and enabled the `plg_search_content` with no luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27389/discussion-between-lodder-and-webprogrammer).